# (System.web.cache)Datacaching is not working on load balancing environment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching, load-balancing

I am using System.web.cache Data cache in aspx.cs file and it is working fine in single server environment and the same code is throwing error in load balancing environment.

kindly advice.

Answer (score 0):

To get data caching to work behind a load balancer you need to specify a distributed cache as your cache provider.  Take a look at [memcached](http://memcached.org/).

Comment: Can i use stickysession in loadbalancer? that will help?

Comment: I believe that would help, yes.  My understanding is stickysession would serve all subsequent requests during that session from the same server.  Of course, you would be caching the data on each server rather than caching it once for both.

Comment: i am sorry, i haven't storing cache in server side. i am just storing in client side at aspx.cs file. When i navigate a menu item on aspx page, the postback happens and its look like the cache is losing its scope.